# How to write Vertx worker verticle - indefinite blocking operation?

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertxoptions

Following class is my worker verticle in which i want to execute a blocking code on recieving a message from event bus on a channel named events-config.

The objective is to generate and publish json messages indefinitely until i receive stop operation message on events-config channel.

I am using executeBlocking to achieve the desired functionality. However since am running the blocking operation indefinitely , vertx blocked threadchecker dumping warnings .

Question:
- Is there a way to disable blockedthreadchecker only for specific verticle ??
- Does the code below adheres to the best practice of executing infinite loop on need basis in vertx ? If not can you please suggest best way to do this ?

```
public class WorkerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WorkerVerticle.class);

    private MessageConsumer<Object> mConfigConsumer;
AtomicBoolean shouldPublish = new AtomicBoolean(true);
private JsonGenerator json = new JsonGenerator();

    @Override
    public void start() {
        mConfigConsumer = vertx.eventBus().consumer("events-config", message -> {
            String msgBody = (String) message.body();
            if (msgBody.contains(PublishOperation.START_PUBLISH.getName()) && !mJsonGenerator.isPublishOnGoing()) {
                logger.info("Message received to start producing data onto kafka " + msgBody);
                vertx.<Void>executeBlocking(voidFutureHandler -> {
                    Integer numberOfMessagesToBePublished = 100000;
                    if (numberOfMessagesToBePublished <= 0) {
                        logger.info("Skipping message publish :"+numberOfMessagesToBePublished);
                        return; // is it best way to do it ??
                    }
                    publishData(numberOfMessagesToBePublished);
                },false, voidAsyncResult -> logger.info("Blocking publish operation is terminated"));

            } else if (msgBody.contains(PublishOperation.STOP_PUBLISH.getName()) && mJsonGenerator.isPublishOnGoing()) {
                logger.info("Message received to terminate " + msgBody);
                mJsonGenerator.terminatePublish();
            }
        });
    }

private void publishData(){
  while(shouldPublish.get()){
   //code to generate json indefinitely until some one reset shouldPublish variable
}
}

}
```

Comment: After struggling with vertx context to execute async stuff , based on feedback got from vertx group. Completablefuture with single thread executor might be the way to do the async stuff..

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use busy loops in your asynchronous code.

Use `vertx.setPeriodic()` or `vertx.setTimer()` instead:

```
vertx.setTimer(20, (l) -> {
    // Generate your JSON
    if (shouldPublish.get()) {
       // Set timer again
    }
});
```